# Scala how to get object property value given name of property in string?

Tags: scala

I wondering how to get object property value given name of property in string in Scala? I saw examples when you get all fields of object using Reflection and iterate over it. But is it possible to call it without iteration? Or may be there is a way to pass object.field to another function without evaluation and evaluate it there and return result?

Comment: You probably want call-by-name: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/functions_call_by_name.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object method invocation using reflection in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953003/dynamic-object-method-invocation-using-reflection-in-scala)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kolmar comment give me right direction to call by name function.